# Can I catch all exceptions thrown from a $compiled directive?

Tags: angularjs

I have an Angular directive (I'll call it `parentDirective`) that `$compile`s some `childDirective` and appends that child directive to itself. A la:

```
// Link function of "parentDirective":
function link($scope, $elem, $attrs) {
    // ...
    var widget = $compile('<child-directive></child-directive>')($scope.$new());
    $elem.find('.some-target').append(widget);
    // ...
}
```

I want to be able to gracefully catch any exceptions that are thrown from within `childDirective`, so that I can display an error message inside the `parentDirective` that indicates that there was a problem.

Now, I know that Angular has an `$exceptionHandler` service that I can override (or I can use a `decorator` to add functionality without overriding), but afaik that is a global thing that can't use to pinpoint the instance of `childDirective` that threw the error in the first place.

One way around this problem that I can think of is to catch errors within `childDirective`, and then call an `errorThrown` function on the `parentDirective`'s controller API, but it would be much nicer if all exceptions are juts caught by the `parentController` itself without any additional logic from `childDirective`. Thoughts? `:)`

**[UPDATE]** Here's a [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/tituswoo/42q8kg4o/) of my problem.

Note: I am required to use Angular 1.2.25 for the time being.

Comment: What sort of specific exceptions are you referring to? Example?

Comment: Hye @charlietfl, I'm primarily trying to catch `thrown` errors... i.e., user-defined exceptions.

Comment: That is not very clear at all

Comment: Ah sorry. So if in the link or controller function of `childDirective`, I do this:

`throw 'Something bad happened!'`

I want `parentDirective` to be able to catch that.

Comment: Well if you throw it why can't you scope it? Just doesn't seem like you have followed this through far enough to make it understandable. If you expect to catch errors from things like `$compile` that is a different story.

Comment: I can scope it from within the directive itself, yes, but I want to be able to catch the errors from the parent directive (if it's possible). `throw`ing isn't something I'm doing manually from within `childDirective`... for example I might have a service that throws something if it hits an error... and that service isn't tied to the directive in any way. Just like how `$exceptionHandler` grabs all Angular expression exceptions that aren't handled, I want to be able to catch all `thrown` exceptions that occur from within `childDirective` in the `parentDirective`.

Comment: go put a real world example demo together ... just like was mentioned in first comment

Comment: @charlietfl added a jsfiddle :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short no you can't do this with a regular error, you could use the scope.$emit to emit an event from the child to notify the parent and use an $on there to get the event but with regular errors the compile code is surrounding the call to the link function with a try catch and calling the $exceptionHandler https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js#L2558

Comment: Updated the link location in the code was pointing to the wrong try catch initially

Comment: Ahh, @shaunhusain I was hoping it wouldn't wrap it with $exceptionHandler, but that makes sense. I try to stay away from events but I guess it really is the only option in my case... exposing an API method on the parentDirective controller would be too limiting. Thanks!